# RTTI for generic type with interface type constraint

Tags: delphi, generics, interface, rtti

Is it possible to inspect the RTTI information for an instance of a generic type with an interface type constraint? The question is probably a little ambiguous so I've created a sample console app to show what I'm trying to do:

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  RTTI,
  SysUtils,
  TypInfo;

type
  TMyAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
  strict private
    FName: string;
  public
    constructor Create(AName: string);
    property Name: string read FName;
  end;

  IMyObjectBase = interface
  ['{E063AD44-B7F1-443C-B9FE-AEB7395B39DE}']
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;

  TMyObjectBase = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyObjectBase)
  public
    procedure DoSomething; virtual;
  end;

  [TMyAttribute('First')]
  TMyFirstRealClass = class(TMyObjectBase)
  public
    procedure DoSomethingDifferent;
  end;

  [TMyAttribute('Second')]
  TMySecondRealClass = class(TMyObjectBase)
  public
    procedure BeSomethingDifferent;
  end;

  TGenericClass<I: IMyObjectBase> = class
  public
    function GetAttributeName(AObject: I): string;
  end;


{ TMyAttribute }

constructor TMyAttribute.Create(AName: string);
begin
  FName := AName;
end;

{ TMyObjectBase }

procedure TMyObjectBase.DoSomething;
begin
end;

{ TMyFirstRealClass }

procedure TMyFirstRealClass.DoSomethingDifferent;
begin
end;

{ TMySecondRealClass }

procedure TMySecondRealClass.BeSomethingDifferent;
begin
end;

{ TGenericClass<I> }

function TGenericClass<I>.GetAttributeName(AObject: I): string;
var
  LContext: TRttiContext;
  LProp: TRttiProperty;
  LAttr: TCustomAttribute;
begin
  Result := '';
  LContext := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
    for LAttr in LContext.GetType(AObject).GetAttributes do
    // ----> [DCC Error] E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'GetType' that can be called with these arguments
      if LAttr is TMyAttribute then
      begin
        Result := TMyAttribute(LAttr).Name;
        Break;
      end;
  finally
    LContext.Free;
  end;
end;

var
  LFirstObject: IMyObjectBase;
  LSecondObject: IMyObjectBase;
  LGeneric: TGenericClass<IMyObjectBase>;
begin
  try
    LFirstObject := TMyFirstRealClass.Create;
    LSecondObject := TMySecondRealClass.Create;

    LGeneric := TGenericClass<IMyObjectBase>.Create;

    Writeln(LGeneric.GetAttributeName(LFirstObject));
    Writeln(LGeneric.GetAttributeName(LSecondObject));

    LGeneric.Free;

    LFirstObject := nil;
    LSecondObject := nil;

    Readln;

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

I need to inspect the object being passed in (AObject), not the generic interface (I).
(Dephi 2010).
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Have you tried doing something like "for LAttr in LContext.GetType(TObject(AObject)).GetAttributes do"? Interface to object casts were added in Delphi 2010. Its not something I like doing but it can help in situations like this.

Comment: Yes that seemed like the obvious solution but it says "Invalid typecast".

Comment: Ok, tested that and it doesn't work. Will edit my answer for now to remove that option.

Comment: You have to use the `as` operator to cast an interface to an object, eg: `for LAttr in LContext.GetType((AObject as TObject).ClassType).GetAttributes`.  Read the documentation: [Casting Interface References to Objects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/2010/en/Interface_References#Casting_Interface_References_to_Objects)

Comment: You might want to change the title because this is not a generic interface (`IMyObjectBase<T>` would be one) but rather a type parameter on a generic type with a constraint on an interface type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possible solutions for this is as follows:

1) I tested with this and it works (XE4):

```
for LAttr in LContext.GetType((AObject as TObject).ClassType).GetAttributes do
```

2) I tested with this and it works (XE4):

```
for LAttr in LContext.GetType(TMyObjectBase(AObject).ClassType).GetAttributes do
```

3) Create method on the interface that returns the object and use that to inspect the object:

```
IMyObjectBase = interface
['{E063AD44-B7F1-443C-B9FE-AEB7395B39DE}']
  procedure DoSomething;
  function GetObject: TObject;
end;

TMyObjectBase = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyObjectBase)
public
  procedure DoSomething; virtual;
  function GetObject: TObject;
end;

{ TMyObjectBase }

function TMyObjectBase.GetObject: TObject;
begin
  Result := Self;
end;
```

And then call it like this:

```
for LAttr in LContext.GetType(AObject.GetObject.ClassType).GetAttributes do
```

Comment: This works with the following small amendment... I needed to add ".ClassType" to the following: for LAttr in LContext.GetType(AObject.GetObject.ClassType).GetAttributes do. I'm not sure if this is a "purist" way of doing it, but it works nonetheless.

Comment: @RickWheeler Casting to TMyObjectBase also seems to work on the surface so I updated the answer to reflect this. As you say, the "purists" might want a word with me :)

Comment: You do not need to have the interface expose a method to retrieve the implementation object.  You can cast the interface directly to `TObject` instead: `for LAttr in LContext.GetType((AObject as TObject).ClassType).GetAttributes do`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I tested with a hard cast and that failed so I assumed a soft cast would fail as well. Will add that as third option. Do you know why is it that a soft cast works and the hard cast is thrown out by the compiler?

Comment: What do you consider to be a "hard" or "soft" cast?

Comment: @RemyLebeau TObject(X) = hard cast, (X as TObject) = soft cast.

Comment: @Graymatter: [Both ways are documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/2010/en/Interface_References#Casting_Interface_References_to_Objects), so what is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: @RemyLebeau "Invalid Typecast" for a hard cast with TObject(AObject), the soft cast works as I expected. Interestingly enough, a hard cast with TMyObjectBase(AObject) does work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau (AObject as TObject) does not work in Delphi 2010, but it seems to work ok in XE5. I'm porting to XE5 now so this is good. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RickWheeler In Delphi 2010 you need to help the compiler a bit more. You have to write `IInterface(AObject) as TObject` or `TObject(IInterface(AObject))`.

Comment: @StefanGlienke It seems like we need to help the XE4 compiler with the second one too - TObject(IInterface(AObject)).

Comment: Gray I think what you call hard cast is known as an unsafe or unchecked typecase. And the `as` operator I would refer to as performing a type checked or just plain checked cast.